# How to use react navigation in other classes?

Tags: react-native

I have a header and a cart button. This button is for navigate to cart Screen. When I press button I have see error.

**Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.navigation.navigate')**

**Header is in Header Class in Header file:**
I use header in other screen like Wallet Screen.

```
<Header style={styles.headerStyle}>
      <Body>
        <Text>Logo</Text>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => {
                      this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        actions: [
                          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Cart' 
      })
                        ],
                      }))
                    }}>
        <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name="washing-machine"/>
        {this.state.cartCountNumber != 0 ?(
            <View style={styles.cartCountBox}>
              <Text>{this.state.cartCountNumber}</Text>
            </View>
         ):null}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </Right>
</Header>
```

Wallet Screen: **When I used on-press in content of wallet worked!**

```
export default class WalletScreen extends React.Component{


render() {
  return (
    <Container>
    <HeaderShow />  // My header is here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    <Content>
    <Text>Wallet Screen</Text>



    // When I use button and on-press here, working fine!



    </Content>
   </Container>
   );
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access this.props.navigation in your Wallet screen, when you add navigation prop to Header in Wallet screen, it will work;

```
export default class WalletScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <HeaderShow navigation={this.props.navigation}/> // My header is here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                <Content>
                    <Text>Wallet Screen</Text>


                    // When I use button and on-press here, working fine!


                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What about this : const HomeTab = () => ();

Comment: I couldn't understand, please can you explain it more detail :)

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Comment: And check Quick Start and const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }]} />
);   . How can I add access to this ?

Comment: Actually you can achieve that from your package(react-nativgation).It has createMaterialTopTabNavigator which works as you want. You don't need additional package. If you need some help, tutorial here https://medium.com/@dooboolab/types-of-navigation-in-react-navigation-v2-bce6d24d94ec

Comment: I know, but I think React Navigation does not support finger swipe --> When I run examples.

Comment: While we set up this package, we must set up react-navigation-gesture-handler too. So we can achieve to the gestures. In  TabNavigatorConfig of createMaterialTopTabNavigator ,swipeEnabled properties is exist. So you can use swipe by swipeEnabled:true (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)

Comment: Have you any idea for this library?

Comment: react-native-tab-view? i have not used it yet. But i used react-navigation.